# Using Variables inside Functions

Tags: function, variables, haskell, functional-programming

Let's say I have a data type called "Coord" which is defined as such:

```
type Coord a = [(Int, Int)]
```

I want to create a variable of type "Coord" to use in my function below. The function takes in a variable of type Coord, and multiplies the x coordinate of each item in the list by 2. It then stores each of these new coordinates in a NEW Coord variable; I'm not sure how to create/declare/use this new variable that I aim to return.

```
foo :: (Eq a) => Coord a -> Coord a
```

Comment: How did you create your first Coord variable?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `type Coord a = [(a, a)]`? Or `newtype Coord a = Coord [(a, a)]`.

Comment: @that other guy I call the function using the first coordinate; for example, in my function call, I would type "foo (1,2)"

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Well, if I were to accept any type in my coordinates, then yeah, but I only want integers; for example, I only want (1,2), (23, 12), (0, 1), etc. and not any other type.

Comment: @DarrelGulseth Your post says you've defined Coord as a list. Do you actually have `type Coord = (Int, Int)` instead? Or are you running `foo [(1,2)]`? If you haven't actually tried to run it yet, please do so and sort that out first (you can use `foo = undefined` until you figure out what to do with it)

Comment: @DarrelGulseth: but then I don't see why (a) you use an `a` type parameter anyway, since it is not used in the "body" of the `type` clause, and (b) why you add an `Eq` constraint.

Comment: @that other guy Yes, I meant to type foo [(1,2)]

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Ok, I will change those two, as they're not necessary.

Comment: Would you know how to do this if you had a `[(Int, Int)]` instead of a `Coord`?

Comment: @that other guy No, I wouldn't; I wouldn't be sure how to declare that list, you know? So I would need to create a new list [(Int, Int)]. But how do I do this? I only know how to access the one that was given to me as a parameter.

Comment: @DarrelGulseth "Well, if I were to accept any type in my coordinates, then yeah, but I only want integers" Then you don't need the `a`. Should be `type Coord = [(Int, Int)]`

Comment: @DarthFennec But that's what I have, right?

Comment: @DarrelGulseth I see `type Coord a = [(Int, Int)]`. There's an `a` in there that does nothing useful for you, unless you're accepting any type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be the manual way of doing something to each element in a list:

```
type Coord = [(Int, Int)]

multiplyXBy2 :: Coord -> Coord
multiplyXBy2 [] = []
multiplyXBy2 ((x, y):rest) = (x*2, y) : multiplyXBy2 rest
```

Here's an invocation via `ghci`:

```
*Main> multiplyXBy2 [(1,2), (3,4)]
[(2,2),(6,4)]
```

For the very basics of using a language, such as how to access list elements passed into a function or how to programmatically build a list, please consider following a tutorial such as LYAH's [Syntax in Functions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) or RWH's [Defining Types, Streamlining Functions](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html)

Comment: Possibly more "advanced" (although not really), but you can simplify this considerably by definding it as `multiplyXBy2 = map (\(x, y) -> (2*x, y))`. Or even `multiplyXBy2 = (map . first) (*2)` (if you `import Control.Arrow`).